# JGroups configuration for internet

Tags: cluster-computing, jgroups

I have successfully got JGroups working on the local network across via different machines using TCP, I can't use multicast. I need the ability for two nodes to communicate over the internet. Changing the addresses to the public ones doesn't seem to work and requires additional configuration.
I've looked at http://www.jgroups.org/manual-3.x/html/protlist.html 
and set external_addr but maybe there is more to set.

How to you set it up to communicate via public addresses?

Configuration:

```
<config xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups-4.0.xsd">

<TCP bind_port="7800"
     recv_buf_size="${tcp.recv_buf_size:130k}"
     send_buf_size="${tcp.send_buf_size:130k}"
     max_bundle_size="64K"
     sock_conn_timeout="300"
client_bind_addr="GLOBAL"
     thread_pool.min_threads="0"
     thread_pool.max_threads="20"
     thread_pool.keep_alive_time="30000"/>

<TCPPING async_discovery="true"
         initial_hosts="${jgroups.tcpping.initial_hosts:52.211.80.63[7801]}"
         port_range="2"/>
<MERGE3  min_interval="10000"
         max_interval="30000"/>
<FD_SOCK/>
<FD timeout="3000" max_tries="3" />
<VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="1500"  />
<BARRIER />
<pbcast.NAKACK2 use_mcast_xmit="false"
               discard_delivered_msgs="true"/>
<UNICAST3 />
<pbcast.STABLE desired_avg_gossip="50000"
               max_bytes="4M"/>
<pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true" join_timeout="2000"
            view_bundling="true"/>
<MFC max_credits="2M"
     min_threshold="0.4"/>
<FRAG2 frag_size="60K"  />
<!--RSVP resend_interval="2000" timeout="10000"/-->
<pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER/>

</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't need `external_addr` unless you are behind a NAT. What you need to do is:

- Set `TCP.bind_addr` (I suggest remove `TCP.client_bind_addr`), e.g. to one of the public IP addresses (`50.x.x.x`)
- `TCPPING.initial_hosts` needs to have all (or a majority) of the members' addresses

Your current configuration doesn't work because (1) `bind_addr` is undefined and (2) `initial_hosts` lists a member at port `7801`, but `TCP.bind_port` is `7800`.

Comment: I am behind a NAT, I have one node in AWS (NAT)ed and one outside(non-NAT) in my test set-up. Is it much different to what you have suggested? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, for the node behind the NAT, set `bind_addr` to the internal and `external_addr` to the public IP address. In `TCPPING.initial_hosts`, include the public address of  the natted node and the public addresses of the other nodes.